# Local and Global variables

Tags: java

I am having trouble storing a node into an arrayList of nodes in two separate for loops (not nested).  There is a big scoping issue.  I need to read in a number of values in the first for loop and store values to this node, but then I have to use another for loop to read in a completely different value no accessable in the first and store it to the same node. I tried making this node global, but it does not seem to work. And I cannot initialize it before the for loop because the values needed to be associated with it are in two separate for loops like I mentioned which are not nested. There has to be a simple solution to this problem I am not seeing.

Comment: If you post the code you have, it might help us figure out the solution you're not seeing. :)

Comment: code?  (that is, "post some code, please...")

Comment: Can you post some of the code? Not sure why you couldn't initialize before the loops.

Comment: This seems to be a design issue, but as for me, I'm not clear on the outside constraints that are driving your design.  Can you tell us more -- why the strange requirements?

Comment: can you post some pseudo code to have a better idea of what you are doing?

Comment: Input is a name followed by an IDnumber, which there are several. Then there are the same repeated IDnumbers and an associated value with them next.  So I need to create a node for the name and a node for the IDnumber. I have to create an edge between them to create a directed graph.  The problem is having to read in all the names and associated IDS given an exact number to how many sets of these there are. So that is the first for loop, then I need to store the associated value of the ID with it but I cannot figure out how to read it all in in one loop

Answer (score 0):

We don't need to see the code -- especially since it is incorrect -- but we do need to see a clear, unambiguous description of the problem. Otherwise if the problem isn't defined than any solution is meaningless since it might be the correct solution to a completely different problem.

Here's my guess at what you're doing:

1. Define the array outside the scope of the 2 loops.
2. Go through the first loop reading into the nodes (I'm guessing that you're initializing an array of nodes, and have to read the information in for each node and store it in the array.
3. Go through the second loop making changes to the nodes that you defined in the first loop.

Now, clearly you must have some way of referencing the node for both loops i.e. a unique id or key, but this isn't clear. It would be helpful if you could describe your problem more clearly.

Comment: Yes you described the problem correctly.  I cannot intialize the node to anything other than null until I get the info from the first loop. It seems that the info in the first loop is not saving to the nodes when I re-access them in the second loop.

Comment: @user700448: Then you've got a bug, but implementing a questionable design is not the way to fix the bug, debugging is.  Your solution is to find out why data is not being saved.

Comment: I am just using a name to reference each node